# awk remove mirrored duplicates from 2 columns

Tags: awk, uniq

**Big question:**
I want a list of the unique combinations between two fields in a data frame.

**Example data:**

```
A   B
C   D
E   F
B   A
C   F
E   F
```

I would like to be able to get the result of 4 unique combinations: AB, CD, EF, and CF.  Since BA and and BA contain the same components but in a different order, I only want one copy (it is a mutual relationship so BA is the same thing as AB)

**Attempt:**

So far I have tried sorting and keeping unique lines:

```
 sort file | uniq
```

but of course that produces 5 combinations:

```
A   B
C   D
E   F
B   A
C   F
```

I do not know how to approach AB/BA being considered the same. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Does the real data have only two chars or can be more than two?

Comment: @George sorry I did not specify - the real data is multiple characters per column, but James and Ed have provided answers that work for multiple characters

Comment: I would suggest to include a multi char sample input/expected output; is possible some solutions to break with multi chars...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic awk approach is to order the index parts:

```
$ awk '!seen[$1>$2 ? $1 FS $2 : $2 FS $1]++' file
A   B
C   D
E   F
C   F
```

Comment: Is storing actual data in the array preferable to just keeping an index?  It seems to me that `awk '$1 FS $2 in seen {next} $2 FS $1 in seen {next} {seen[$1 FS $2]} 1' file` would be easier on memory, even though it's a few more characters of code.

Comment: `seen` will contain exactly the same values either way, the unique set of $1,$2 pairs. Oh, I see what you're saying - no need to keep the count. That'll be a drop in the ocean and slightly more memory for slightly better efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

another `awk` magic

```
awk '!a[$1,$2] && !a[$2,$1]++' file
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk '($1$2 in a){next}{a[$1$2];a[$2$1]}1' file
A   B
C   D
E   F
C   F
```

Explained:

```
($1$2 in a) { next }     # if duplicate in hash, next record
{ a[$1$2]; a[$2$1] } 1   # hash reverse also and output
```

It works for single char fields. If you want to use it for longer strings, add `FS` between fields, like `a[$1 FS $2]` etc. (thanks @EdMorton).

Comment: @ghoti how it is useful or constructive to make fun of me? I am just learning coding and try hard to ask questions in an organized way following the structure outlined on this site. This is the final step in a longer problem I am working on that is primarily using awk. If you don't have anything nice to say, please just keep it to yourself!

Comment: @EdMorton True, true.

Comment: Have you forgot a `||` in your solution just before 1? You have include it in your explanation but not in your code.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, it is clearer. First I missed the `{}`s in your post and didn't quite get the logic (literally)...

Comment: @user4670961, my comment was not intended to make fun of you, it was intended to highlight the fact that you are asking for help with `awk`, but there is no `awk` code in your question, which I mentioned in a comment on your question as well. As I keep commenting, StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. I'm happy to just provide a downvote on the question if that's less stressful for you. I often provide comments instead because I tend to forget about downvotes, and I'd prefer to remove them once questions get improved. Comments help with that.